# Can I destroy and recreate a Git remote branch in one command?

Tags: git

In Git, I sometimes work on long-running branches. I like to rebase on master from time to time to make merging easier when I'm ready.

After rebasing, I can't push a previously-pushed branch to a remote, because my branch's history no longer agrees with the remote's history of that branch. So I have to delete it first.

This is my current workflow:

```
git checkout my_branch
git rebase master
git push origin :my_branch  # Delete remote version of the branch
git push origin my_branch   # Push up my new version of history on this branch
```

Is there a single, atomic command that could replace the last two commands?

Comment: I didn't know you can't push a rebased branch. Anyone knows why?! Rebase seems to be a fairly common operation, why wouldn't it "just work"?

Comment: Quoting http://help.github.com/rebase _"It is considered bad practice to rebase commits which you have already pushed to a remote repo. Doing so may invoke the wrath of the git gods... you have been warned."_

Comment: @Stefan, oh well, good old git-merge it is for me then.

Comment: @Shahbaz - Git has the concept of 'porcelain' and 'plumbing' commands, the former being built from the latter. For example, `git pull` is really a combination of `fetch` and `merge`. I imagine that `push` is similar. `merge` and `rebase` are incompatible, because `merge` is about finding common commits and adding missing ones. `rebase` in this case means the two copies of the branch don't have any common history before they split from `master`.

Comment: @Stefan - I would never try this on master, but in my team, we often have 'personal' branches that nobody else will work on; they are essentially backups of our work in case the building burns.

Comment: @NathanLong, isn't rebase something like apply diff of shaX to shaY to the beginning of my branch, so it looks like I branched off at a later commit? That is, if you rebase to HEAD, it's basically merging all your branch's commits with HEAD, but keeping them in the separate branch. Isn't that true? It looks pretty much similar to merge from what I understood

Comment: @Shahbaz - every commit is the summary of the entire history of the repo up to that point. When you rebase, you make it as though you had branched at a different point, so the end result is an entirely different set of commits, making the same changes but from a different starting point. Like any other command that changes history (for example, `git reset --soft HEAD~4`, then a single commit instead of several), this will cause problems if anyone else has a copy of that branch; hence the guideline @Stefan cited.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are allowed to rewrite the remote branch, you can use `git push --force my_remote my_branch`.

Comment: This will solve the question as asked, but Stefan is on the right track. Rebasing commits you've already pushed to a remote is generally not a good practice.

Comment: Well, if you are the only one working on that branch it's probably okay.

Comment: @Stefan - that is exactly my case; it's my exclusive branch. I wouldn't do it otherwise.

Comment: Alternative syntax for the same effect would be `git push origin +my_branch`. The '+' says it's ok to overwrite the destination branch.

Comment: @MichaelWild - would you correct that to `git push remote_name my_branch --force`? I always include the remote name when I push, but on a force push, I'm even more anxious to be specific.

Comment: @twalberg I know about the `+` syntax, but I always find it to be a bit arcane and prefer the verbosity of `--force`.

Answer (score 3):

That's right, `git push -f` is appropriate in the example.

The reason being there's no need to re-create the entire branch, since all the commits pre-rebase remain the same.

We only need to overwrite our new rebased local commits to our remote repo that contains the non-rebased stale commits.

---

In my similar use case, `git push -f` wasn't viable as my remote repo got removed by mistake, so I [created a git-create shell script in my PATH](https://coderwall.com/p/mnwcog/create-new-github-repo-from-command-line) that let me easily:

```sh
git create my_branch
git push -f
```