# How to maintain a branch just for my pull requests when working in group?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have the permissions to directly push to master, but instead in my team we're following a more polite mechanism:

- `git pull`
- `git checkout -b myBranch`
- `git merge master`
- do my stuff...git add...etc.
- `git push origin myBranch --force`
- Then "ask" on the bitbucket web GUI a Pull Request

But I'm wondering if there's a more straightforward way to say "I don't want the local copy of myBranch anymore, just act as if it were a new branch, also for remote"

I've read [Can I destroy and recreate a Git remote branch in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851720/can-i-destroy-and-recreate-a-git-remote-branch-in-one-command) and I'm ok with remote deleting, but the rebase thing overwhelms me a little bit.

EDIT: Also if the current way to work leads to errors in sync I would like to know

Comment: The --force during the push is the most straightforward way of overwriting what the remote branch pointer points to. If you can be a little more specific about what is confusing you about the rebase we can help...

Comment: Thanks. I would like to have less steps (maybe a one liner?) to do the same I'm doing now, in order to make harder forgetting steps. I'm not exactly confused about the rebase (to be honest i didn't use it ever) is just that it looks like "too much" for this

Comment: gotcha, I posted an answer but it is very similar to what you were already doing. Feel free to post comments on it if you would like further clarification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't want the local copy of `myBranch` anymore, just act as if it were a new branch, also for remote

If you just want a brand new branch `myBranch` from the current master (losing all the history of `myBranch`):

```
git fetch
git checkout -B mybranch origin/master
```

That command will reset your branch: from [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

> If `-B` is given, `<new_branch>` is created if it doesn’t exist; otherwise, it is reset.
>   This is the transactional equivalent of:

```
$ git branch -f <branch> [<start point>]
$ git checkout <branch>
```

Then:

```
# work

# Before pushing, make sure you are up-to-date
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
git push --force -u origin myBranch
```

The remote branch will be reset to your new `myBranch` history.

Comment: Thanks. However, when I do this I get: $ git push -u origin testsMizar
Password for 'https://malarres@bitbucket.org':
To https://malarres@bitbucket.org/pathTo/project.git
 ! [rejected]        testsMizar -> testsMizar (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://malarres@bitbucket.org/pathTo/project.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details. (continues)

Comment: @malarres true, a rebase change the history of `mybranch`. Do a `git push --force` at the end

Comment: (cont'd) of course I did what it says and I get $ git pull
Password for 'https://malarres@bitbucket.org':
Already up-to-date.

Comment: wow you're faster answering that I am editing a big THANKS to you!

Comment: @malarres no, push --force. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Based upon the initial steps you included, as well as your comment, here are the steps I would take starting at the beginning of a new feature or bug fix:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout -b myBranch

... do work ... add/commit/etc

... periodically when you want to get the latest from master...
git fetch
git rebase origin/master

git push --force origin myBranch
```

During the rebase step, of course you can have code conflicts, just like with a merge. The process for resolving these conflicts will be very similar. Git provides instructions as to how to proceed in these steps.

So, these steps are very similar to what you originally posted, but the rebase will make your history cleaner (as opposed to the merge) since it prevents having meaninless merge-commits.

Comment: So there's no way to make it more straightforward :(

Comment: Of course thanks for the help. I'll start to rebase (not on this repo) to gain experience with it

Answer (score 0):

I have you some text for reading :-)

Good article, how branches could do a successful job in development.

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: I don't have clear if you're suggesting that I'm on a "permanent hotfix" branch or if I'm development whereas master is release. Could you please explain?

Comment: For further development you have a development branch. master is for releasing and tagging. hotfix branches only for hotfixing. Before you are releasing you have release branch. Exactly how it is described in the article. Have fun! Cheers

Comment: ahh ok. Thanks for the tip. However I'm not allowed atm to change the workflow of the team. But this is something that we must address on our next department meeting!

Comment: I wish you great success!